# Node child_process can't pipe stdout when the child process gets aborted

Tags: node.js, pipe, stdout, child-process, bad-alloc

I want to compile code (pawn language), pipe all the compiler output, and then match all diagnostics using regex.

The thing is, for some reason, the compiler *sometimes* crashes with this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

which seems to be a common thing in C++ programs, after googling about it.

So if I do this:

```js
child_process.execFile('./amxxpc', ['source.sma'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  ...
})
```

`stdout` ends up being an empty string, stderr is the `std::bad_alloc` error I pasted above, and `error` looks like this:

```
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
  code: null,
  killed: false,
  signal: 'SIGABRT',
  cmd: './amxxpc source.sma'
}
```

So I don't get why `stdout` is an empty string. If I run the exact same command in a terminal, and I ignore stderr, I get some diagnostics in stdout, which I want to be able to read when spawning it with child_process

```
> ./amxxpc source.sma 2>/dev/null
AMX Mod X Compiler 1.9.0.5294
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 ITB CompuPhase
Copyright (c) 2004-2013 AMX Mod X Team

source.sma(2) : error 029: invalid expression, assumed zero
source.sma(2 -- 4) : warning 215: expression has no effect
source.sma(4) : warning 217: loose indentation
source.sma(4) : error 029: invalid expression, assumed zero
source.sma(4) : error 017: undefined symbol "plugin_init"
source.sma(4) : fatal error 107: too many error messages on one line

Compilation aborted.
4 Errors.
```

just in case, this is the pawn code:

```cpp
foo() {]

public plugin_init() {
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, when the compiler is executed in a real terminal, TTY, it flushed the stdout buffer on every line, whereas if its output is being piped, it doesn't flush "as often" as if it was a real TTY. It gets aborted before flushing, and the stdout buffer is lost.

So as a solution, I'm using the [`node-pty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty) package to emulate a TTY terminal, so the program flushes to stdout before getting aborted. Now I can get the compiler diagnostics, even if it gets aborted shortly after that.